# Camera capture device exposure mode lock

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, avcapturedevice

I'm trying to lock the exposure with the exposure point but it seems it doesn't work when I tried in my device. Although the Camera app works when you long press tap the screen to lock the exposure and the focus as well, but when trying it with my own app with the following lines of code, it doesn't work. Did I miss something on the configuration?

```
if ([_captureInput.device isExposureModeSupported:AVCaptureExposureModeLocked] && [_captureInput.device lockForConfiguration:NULL] && [_captureInput.device isExposurePointOfInterestSupported]) 
{
[_captureInput.device setExposurePointOfInterest:pointOfInterest];
[_captureInput.device setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeLocked];
[_captureInput.device unlockForConfiguration];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

an example of how to lock the configuration if you were to change the flash mode for example is like this:

```
AVCaptureDevice *temp = [[[[self captureSession] inputs] lastObject] device];

if ([temp isFlashModeSupported:AVCaptureFlashModeOn]) {
        NSError *error;
        bool locked = [temp lockForConfiguration:&error];
        if (locked) {
            switch (self.flashMode.intValue) {
                case 0: // Off
                    [temp setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOff];
                    break;
                case 1: // On
                    [temp setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn];
                    break;
                case 2: // Auto
                    [temp setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeAuto];
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Could not lock for configuration");
        }

    }
```

Edit: THis is JUST an example (but it should work), as you can see i get the capture device in a very weird way because i dont save it anywhere if you had it saved or if u were handling it differently it would also work.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I've tried it in torch and flash and it worked. I wonder why it is not working on exposure just like in the camera app that the brightness/contrast changes when you long press tap the screen and locks the auto focus/auto exposure.

Comment: You are testing for 3 conditions in your if. try them separately with a flag and see if any fails. also NSLOG the error param in the lock one to see why its not being locked, if not being locked is the problem. I remember something like it is not possible to lock if its already locked or something.

Comment: I've tried also doing that with NSLog and it shows with the log that the device is locked with the exposure point of interest. The weird thing is when the background light changed, the exposure also changed which means that it is not actually locked. And when you changed the tap area for the points of interest, nothing happens on the preview screen.

Comment: I've tried to manage it. You need to have an observer that when you want to lock it, set the exposure of interest and after it has been adjusted using the AVCaptureExposureContinuosMode, you then locked it.